# General conditions on generating sets for dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, finitely-generated

It's well-known that, for any $n$, we can consider

$D_n = \langle r, f | r^n = e, f^2 = e, r^k \not = e (0 < k < n), fr= r^{-1} f\rangle$;

However, not all two element generating sets for $D_n$ satisfy these conditions: if we take $\{f, fr\}$. then $D_n = \langle f, fr \rangle$, but these two elements have order two. So my questions is: are there general (and interesting) conditions such that *any* two element generating set for $D_n$ must satisfy?

Comment: Note that in writing a presentation you don't need to state $r^k \ne e (\text{for } 0 < k < n)$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti - I noticed that. But if $n$ is odd, both $f^n$ and $(fr)^n$ will not be the identity, so they don't satisfy even the more liberal condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characterization for a generating pair $x,y$ is either one of $x,y$ (say $x$) is a reflection and $y$ generates the group of rotations (so its order is $n$), or $x,y$ are both reflections and the order of $xy$ is $n$. It's easy to go from one presentation to the other; given a generating set of the second type, $\{x,xy\}$ is a generating set of the first type, and given a generating set of the first type, $\{x,xy\}$ is a generating set of the second type. It's not too hard to see that this exhausts all possibilities. Try to prove it.

Comment: Here's a sketch: if $x, y$ are both rotations, then they don't generate a reflection, so either one is a reflection and the other a rotation, or else they are two reflections. If they are a reflection and a rotation, then the rotation must generate the group of rotations, because the product of a reflection and a rotation is a reflection. Finally, if they are both reflections, then their product is a rotation, which must generate the whole group of rotations (following similar lines of the previous situation). Is that right?

Comment: If $n \geq 3$, that is.

Comment: @Nagase Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: @Nagase No problem.